# Adding foreign keys error: ORA-02298: cannot validate - parent keys not found

Tags: oracle

I essentially have 2 tables, one named table1 and another called table2.

I want to insert a foreign key into table2 and have it make sure it is linked as a parent to table1 (since both tables have the same column called: EMPNO).

This is what I tried:

```
ALTER TABLE table2 
ADD FOREIGN KEY (EMPNO) 
REFERENCES table1(EMPNO)
```

however I receive an error from my live SQL when running it:

ORA-02298: cannot validate (SQL_EOTBMPLTBLKHWFZRYEHITBYIH.) - parent keys not found

Comment: check out this for correct syntax of constraints https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp

Comment: This error means what it says. You have values in the EMPNO column in table2 which do not exist in the same column in table1. You must fix that first.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This error means that `table2` has foreign key values that do not exist in the parent table, `table1`. To identify them, run a query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT EMPNO FROM table2 WHERE EMPNO NOT IN (
    SELECT EMPNO FROM table1)
```

Fix those bad key values and then run your `ALTER TABLE` again.